# Comparing two flat files in linux (bash), taking what is missing and putting it in the first file?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am currently trying to compare two flat files in bash.  The first file will have three columns separated by | and the second will have two columns separated by |. I want to take the input that is missing from the second file and put it into the first. I am only concerned with taking over the two missing columns from file 2 to file 1.

example files

**file one:**

> a|blue|3
>
> b|yellow|1
>
> c|green|2

**file two:**

> a|blue
>
> b|yellow
>
> c|green
>
> d|purple

**Output file:**

> a|blue|3
>
> b|yellow|1
>
> c|green|2
>
> d|purple

Comment: You've shown us two files; show us how you'd like them to look *after* the operation.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have provide an example of what the output (file one) file should look like after the process is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
# Set the input field separator to "|"
awk -F'|' '

# Load the second file into an array called "a". NR==FNR allows us to perform this action
# until first file is complete 
NR==FNR { a[$0]; next }

# We check the existence of first and second column of first file in array. If it is present
# we delete that array element. 1 at the end allows us to print the line from first file as is. 
($1 FS $2 in a) { delete a[$1 FS $2] }1

# This action takes place at the very end. Whatever is left in our array we iterate through
# and print it. This can cause the output to appear in any order hence sort is needed. 
END { for (l in a) print l }' f2 f1
```

**Output**:

```
$ head f*
==> f1 <==
a|blue|3
c|green|2
b|yellow|1

==> f2 <==
a|blue
c|green
b|yellow
d|purple

$ awk -F'|' '
NR==FNR { a[$0]; next }
($1 FS $2 in a) { delete a[$1 FS $2] }1
END { for (l in a) print l }' f2 f1
a|blue|3
c|green|2
b|yellow|1
d|purple
```

Comment: That almost what I want to have. Now what would be the best way to make sure it is sorted by column one  and that f1 is wrote over so it looks like the output on your example.

Comment: You can pipe the output to `sort` so something like `awk ... | sort -t'|' -k1`. `GNU awk 4.1` allows infile changes. If you don't have that your best option would be to re-direct it to a new file and rename it. so `awk ... | sort ... > tmp && mv tmp f1`

Comment: Thanks

for your help JS.

Comment: One last question. Would you mind giving a quick run down of what some of the flags do or just a quick explanation. I want to understand this better for the future.

Comment: @user2607210 Updated to add comments. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks JS that helped a lot. I would give you rep but I am too new.